# CMake: How do I add a function to an installed config?

Tags: cmake

I am creating a library which I am building and installing with CMake. In the `CMakeLists.txt` is `install(TARGETS mylib ...)` to install the library itself and `install(EXPORT ...)` to create a CMake config. The CMake config means that the library can be found with `find_package()` by applications wanting to use the library from their own `CMakeLists.txt`. So far, nothing surprising.

But in addition to that I have `useful_fn.cmake` that contains a useful CMake function that I want to make available to the applications' `CMakeLists.txt`. I can install it manually with install `install(FILE useful_fn.cmake)`, but how will the applications know where to find it? Can it be referenced from the config?

Even better, could the CMake config include the installed version directly? So merely running `find_package(mylib)` provides access to this CMake function? I could do this if I wrote my whole mylib-config.cmake by hand, rather than than getting CMake to generate it like it currently does, but I would really rather not do that just so that I can add one line (`include(.../usefulfn.cmake)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is misconception that CMake should generate `XXXConfig.cmake` script. As opposite, intended behavior that CMake generates every other script (names can be any):

- `XXXConfigTargets.cmake` with `install(EXPORT)`
- `XXXConfigVersion.cmake` with `write_basic_package_version_file()`

and these scripts are included in the `XXXConfig.cmake` script **written by hands**, where you may define additional things:

```
# File: XXXConfig.cmake

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/XXXConfigVersion.cmake)
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/XXXConfigTargets.cmake)
# Here you may provide additional functions and other things.
function(my_func)
  ...
endfunction()
```

See more in the [CMake packaging documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#id12).

Comment: Thanks, that is massively helpful – I had no idea I was doing it wrong. Doing it properly makes my original question easy I will install `helpful_fn.cmake` alongside these other files and add `include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/helpful_fn.cmake)` along with these in my hand-written config.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify further, there is a module that helps your configure valid and relocatable config file.

See macro `configure_package_config_file` provided by [CMakePackageConfigHelpers](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html) module.

As mentioned by @Tsyvarev, the `XXXConfig.cmake` file should still be written by hand but configured with `configure_package_config_file` instead of `configure_file`.