# CMake Exported Lib - Cannot find include/lib paths in client app

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, export, shared-libraries

So I have two CMake projects, MyLib and MyApp. I build, install and export MyLib to a custom directory (right now just using my desktop:  /Users/MyName/Desktop/InstallDir) and then I want to use find_package() to find MyLin when building MyApp.

So my CMakeLists.txt file for MyLib has the following code:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../install")

target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC 
                      $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include> )

install(TARGETS mylib
        EXPORT mylib-targets 
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include 
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

install(EXPORT mylib-targets 
        NAMESPACE mylib::
        FILE mylib-config.cmake
        DESTINATION lib/cmake/mylib)

export(PACKAGE mylib)
```

This creates a mylib-config.cmake file in install/cmake/mylib

Then in MyApp's CMakeLists.txt file I have the following code

```
set(mylib_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../install/lib/cmake/mylib")
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../install")

find_package(mylib REQUIRED)
message("Include dirs: "  ${mylib_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
message("Libs: " ${mylib_LIBRARIES} )
```

However, when I build MyApp, mylib_INCLUDE_DIRS and mylib_LIBRARIES are both empty. If I check the mylib-config.cmake file, those variables are not defined in there either, but I thought that when exporting a package, those were automatically generated?

What steps am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export file, generated by CMake, defines *IMPORTED* targets, not a variables. Exactly for those targets you set `NAMESPACE` option in the `install(EXPORT)` command.

Variables like `XXX_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `XXX_LIBRARIES` are set by some `FindXXX.cmake` scripts (old style). Also, these variables can be set in `XXXConfig.cmake` script, if it is written manually (that script can include the script generated by CMake, and can wrap *IMPORTED* targets with variables).

Comment: Thank you. So how exactly do I set those variables in the XXXConfig.cmake script and have it include the script generated by CMake?

Comment: Set `mylib_LIBRARIES` variable to the target, defined in CMake generated script. Like there https://stackoverflow.com/q/51290927/3440745.

Comment: So to clarify, I need to set the variable to the mylib target in my CMakeLists.txt file, and then when CMake autogenerates the mylib-config.cmake file, that variable will be defined in there as well? 

What is the command for setting the variable to the target?

Comment: "What is the command for setting the variable to the target?" - `set(mylib_LIBRARIES mylib::mylib)`. So, when user will link with `${mylib_LIBRARIES}` expression, he/she will actually link with *IMPORTED* target `mylib::mylib`. Note, that setting variables in `FindXXX.cmake`/`XXXConfig.cmake` is an old style. New code should prefer IMPORTED targets. Exactly those are generated by CMake.