# cmake include dependencies using find_package from installed target

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I am currently migrating a couple of CodeBlock projects to use CMake and Visual Studio Code. I am facing an issue related to the include directory not being known by the consuming target.

I followed a guide so far as I was not aware of the "modern CMake way" using targets at all until yet. Mainly referring to here: https://rix0r.nl/blog/2015/08/13/cmake-guide/ and the official CMake docs.
There are two libraries (.so). One of them needs to other one to be there (build) when it get's loaded by the application later on.
I am not sure if everything is even intended to work like I assume it to work so I will just continue with the code and the expected result.

Library A (which is needed by Library B) has following CMakeLists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(A)

set(SOURCE somesource.c)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
add_library(JNI SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET JNI PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include/linux)
set_property(TARGET JNI PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${JNI_LIBRARIES})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PUBLIC 
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include/linux>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)

install(DIRECTORY include/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Config
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})

install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Config DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/cmake)
```

Notice I only have one include file which is public and located in "include", so its used by the library itself but should also be part of the install interface
used by the "consuming" target.

Library B (which uses Library A and its header)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(B)

set(SOURCE somesource.c)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE})

find_package(A REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

So in Library B I assume that I do not need to add the include_directories from Library A again. This is why I actually did the target approach so there is no need to keep track of linker/include dependencies. "find_package" should handle these on it's own right? I do not link neither because it is a shared object, not a static library.
Both libraries use the same CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ofc and library A has been installed (make install). I double-checked on this. In case of using a different prefix or not doing the install, CMake already complains about not finding it.

So considering the issue now:
Within a source file from library B, I am using

```
#include <libcobjava.h>
```

resulting in an error when building as the compiler complains about "No such file or directory" Am I missing something? The file is definitely located at
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/include.

Apart from that as I am still new to CMake: Is this even the way you would do things if you own all the source?

## Edit: Some more details on the follow-up issue as discussed in comments. Library A is libcobjava.

First I had the target_include_directories part as following (including the path where jni.h is located in `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:`)

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PUBLIC 
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include/linux> 
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include/linux>        
)
```

results in following error:

```
[cmake] Configuring done
[cmake] CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
[cmake]   Target "libcobjava" INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property contains path:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     "/media/rbs42/data/Gebos/RBS42/tools/libcobjava/${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
[cmake] 
[cmake]   which is prefixed in the source directory.
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] Generating done
[cms-driver] Error during CMake configure: [cmake-server] Failed to compute build system.
```

This is why I removed `$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include/linux>` from `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE` again.

The actual error I am getting in library B now is during compiling:

```
[build] /media/rbs42/data/rbs42/usr/include/libcobjava.h:1:10: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
[build]  #include <jni.h>
```

because library B does not have the include directories from library A that are not included in the `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE`. This is what one would expect. And thats the reason I added the following code before in library A.

```
set_property(TARGET JNI PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include/linux)
```

which I assumed is taking care of propagating the include dependencies from library A to the "consuming" library B, although they are not part of the `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE`.

Comment: In the project `B` you have `find_package(A REQUIRED)` but never uses results of this call. It should be `target_link_libraries(B A)` for link the `B` library with `A` and "consume" its include directories.

Comment: Thanks! I was misunderstanding target_link_libraries. That fixed the issue.
However, now I get an error about a missing include library A uses (not part of the public header) in library B. More specific it is JNI which is not a project I have the source/cmake for. I tried adding
`find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
add_library(JNI SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET JNI PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set_property(TARGET JNI PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${JNI_LIBRARIES})` (similar to the sample)
in library A, but this did not solve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: Check content of `${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS}`, and check that given directory **actually** contains required headers.

Comment: I made sure and using the hardcoded path again. The path is used in lib A for building and working fine there so I can exclude the path for being incorrect.
I updated the CMakeLists.txt for Library A. Library B is unchanged.
Library B now complains about `#include <jni.h>`, which is the first line in headerFromA.hpp (which was unknown before). 
Thanks for your time, would be really glad if we can work this out.

Comment: I am not sure, but construction `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:XXX>` should be **repeated** for every include directory; you cannot use single construction for several include directories.

Comment: I will look this up! But is the build_interface even relevant for library B? I assumed only the install interface is taken into account, which seems to work fine now (considering library B knows about the header from library A).
Is there anything more to take care of when I want the dependcies from library A (JNI in this case) also to be taken into account in library B? I am still googling in the meanwhile but could not find any concrete example expect boost, which differs a bit from mine.

Comment: Oh, yes, `BUILD_INTERFACE` is used only for build A project. BTW, `B` project sees only `INSTALL_INTERFACE`, into which you include only `include/` subdirectory (under installation prefix). Do you have JNI files copied into this directory? Please, provide **exact code** which you use, **exact error message** which  you got, and show which files do you have under install directory. Otherwise it is a *guessing game*.

Comment: I added an EDIT part in the main post where I discribed the things I did already and the exact error. Thanks again for your effort! JNI files are not located in this include directory I have in my install_interface. See description above

Comment: 1. You have `JNI` target with many properties set.. but you **never use** it (back to the my first comment). 2. CMake error "... prefixed in the source directory." is for purpose, do not try to *overcome* it - *fix* it instead. Main intention of the **installed** project is to work **without** *sources* (e.g. after removing them). You may install JNI library *separately* from your project, so JNI include directory will point outside of your project. Or install JNI headers of that library along with your project, so include directory will refer to installation one.

Comment: I guess I will end up with the second approach to have a "fix" instead of a "workaround".
But where am I supposed to use `JNI` target? Isn't `add_library(JNI SHARED IMPORTED)` with the properties already enough or does this only affect libcobjava and not the consuming library? Putting `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} JNI)` in addition fails because JNI evaluates to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so;/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so` and hence gcc complains about 'No such file or directory' when compiling libcobjava

Comment: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} JNI)` is a proper way for use JNI. You show the list of `.so` files, which are part of JNI libraries. They all should exist on your PC. BTW, linking with IMPORTED library is propagated to the config file *directly*. CMake expects from you to add appropriate code into the config file, which creates that imported target again (with all required properties).

Comment: The libraries exist on the filesystem, but I assume the `;` is the issue.
libcobjava compiles when I seperate the `target_link_libraries` like:
`target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so)`
But library B still fails to find the jni include. You mean IMPORTED library is NOT propagated? What do I need to add in the config file? I did not write the config file on my own. It is created via the install rules in my CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Do I need to create seperate JNI config file like 
`install(EXPORT JNIConfig DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/cmake)` for the JNI target? I need to leave the office now but try it latest by tomorrow if this is what you meant.

Comment: Oh, just notice that - you are attempting to make `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property to be a **list** of libraries. This doesn't work. That property should contain only **one** library. You may link your IMPORTED library with other libraries. "I did not write the config file on my own. It is created via the install rules in my CMakeLists.txt" - You are actually expected to write the `XXXConfig.cmake` file by hands; CMake only helps you in that purpose. See that my answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51290927/cmake-how-do-i-add-a-function-to-an-installed-config/51293903#51293903