# CMake variable defined in a library available in global scope

Tags: c++, cmake

What is the best way to define CMake variables in a header-only library and make them available in its dependents scope?

e.g:

```
# Header-only library CMakeLists.txt
[...]
add_library(SomeLibrary INTERFACE)
set(FOO "Foo is defined" PARENT_SCOPE)     # this doesn't work
```

```
# Top level CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(Dummy main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Dummy SomeLibrary)

get_property(..?)

message("Foo=${FOO}")       # Foo=
```

Comment: A lot of useful information about the library is provided via its target properties. So providing a variable could be not needed. You say that setting PARENT_SCOPE variable doesn't work. What is layout of your project, which uses header-only library.

Comment: I kind of voluntarily omitted that this was distributed through Conan because I don't want it interfering with the way the CMakeLists are written - but in terms of layout, this header-only library is a conan package that is a build requirement of the parent project.

Comment: As a workaround, I found that configuring a file to be included in the parent project's recipe can do exactly what I want but it feels a bit hacky?

Comment: As far as I understand, Conan works with packages via `find_package()` mechanism. So transferring the variable via configuration file, created for your library, will be sufficient. See that question about the way of doing so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51290927/cmake-how-do-i-add-a-function-to-an-installed-config/51293903#51293903. In any case, it is better to include notion of the Conan both to the question post and to the tags.

Comment: There is no global scope.  The `PARENT_SCOPE` adds it to the parent not the root/top-level scope.  `Each new directory or function creates a new scope.`