# CMake: how do I avoid getting absolute paths in INTERFACE target properties?

Tags: cmake

**General problem:**
I get absolute paths in my `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` and `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` properties for a target, which is a problem because these variables get exported via the `install(EXPORT)`, which will mean trouble if anything is relocated. I traced the origin of these absolute paths back to the `find_package` command, which (for some but not all packages) sets variables like `Boost_LIBRARIES` with absolute paths. When they are used with e.g. the `target_link_libraries` command, they end up in the `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`.

**Q:** How do I best avoid the exported target properties from being poluted with absolute paths?

The trivial solution is obviously to just overwrite the respective variables with some strings that only name the libraries (hardcoded), but I guess there should be a better way.

**Specific problem (Example):** see https://github.com/cartographer-project/cartographer/issues/1688

---

**EDIT:**
My (modified) `cartographer-config.cmake.in` 
(note: you can ignore the stuff associated to `ceres`, since that does not give me trouble, eventhough it places an abs path in the hint):

```
# Copyright 2016 The Cartographer Authors
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

#  Usage from an external project:
#    In your CMakeLists.txt, add these lines:
#
#    find_package(cartographer REQUIRED)
#    target_link_libraries(MY_TARGET_NAME PUBLIC cartographer)

@PACKAGE_INIT@

set_and_check(CARTOGRAPHER_CMAKE_DIR "@PACKAGE_CARTOGRAPHER_CMAKE_DIR@")

find_dependency(Boost)
find_dependency(Lua)

set(CERES_DIR_HINTS @Ceres_DIR@)

if (cartographer_FIND_QUIETLY)
   find_package(Ceres QUIET HINTS ${CERES_DIR_HINTS})
elseif (cartographer_FIND_REQUIRED)
   find_package(Ceres REQUIRED HINTS ${CERES_DIR_HINTS})
else ()
   find_package(Ceres HINTS ${CERES_DIR_HINTS})
endif()

include("${CARTOGRAPHER_CMAKE_DIR}/CartographerTargets.cmake")
```

Comment: `install(EXPORT)` So did you use `BUILD_INTERFACE` and `INSTALL_INTERFACE` as advertised in [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html)? Please show the code - how does your `target_link_libraries` line look like?

Comment: the code: https://github.com/cartographer-project/cartographer/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt
as far as I can tell, at least `INSTALL_INTERFACE` is used as advertised.

Comment: Original `cartographer-config.cmake` has line `include("${CARTOGRAPHER_CMAKE_DIR}/CartographerTargets.cmake")` which includes CMake-generated file for the `EXPORT`-ed target. I don't see that line in your config file.

Comment: I dropped that line when I copied it. Now I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I best avoid the exported target properties from being poluted with absolute paths?

Hide **absolute** paths behind the IMPORTED target:

```
# Express an external library via IMPORTED target
add_library(lib_external IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_external PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${XXX_LIBRARY} (some absolute path)"
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${XXX_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES} (some absolute path)"
)

# Use external library via the target created
target_link_libraries(my_lib lib_external)
```

Such way, the config file for `my_lib` will contain only the name of the IMPORTED library, but not its properties.

In the config file for your project you just need to create IMPORTED target with the same name and fill its properties according to the current machine (where your project is *used*).

`find_package` for most of modern packages (including Boost) already returns an IMPORTED target. In the configuration file for your project you may use [find_dependency](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html), which discovers the package on the current machine and creates an IMPORTED target again.

For old packages, which `find_package` just returns `XXX_LIBRARIES` and `XXX_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` variables, you may create the IMPORTED target *manually*. In the configuration file for your project you may use `find_dependency` too, and again create IMPORTED target *manually*.

---

When use `find_dependency` macro, remember to pass the **same parameters** which you have passed to the `find_package()` in the project's `CMakeLists.txt`. This is primary about `COMPONENTS` parameter and variables like `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS`, which affects on the package searching.

If you want to specify `VERSION` requirement, then this requirement should express **binary compatibility** of the library on the *target machine* with the library against which the project has been **actually built**.

`HINST` and `PATHS` options for `find_package` are unlikely needed to be transferred to the `find_dependency`: call to the `find_dependency` is processed on the *target machine*, which paths could be different from ones on the *build machine*.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, if the find script already defines IMPORTED targets (like boost does) you suggest to just go with e.g. `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Boost::boost)` correct? unfortunately I get undefined symbol errors when doing this.
Furthermore, if I try the solution above with e.g. lua (which does not come with IMPORTED target), I end up having `lib_external` in the exported `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`, which won't be any good for the consuming project (downstream) I suppose

Comment: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Boost::boost)` is a proper way for include Boost. Note, that there are **several** IMPORTED target with `Boost::` prefix. Probably, you forgot to link with some of them when get "undefined symbols" error? Both with `Boost` and `Lua` you would have IMPORTED targets in the EXPORT file. This is not a problem while you resolve (create) these targets in the configuration file of your project.

Comment: CMake has a nice description of packaging: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-packages.7.html. There they describe an example with `ClimbingStats` project which uses `Stats` external library. And resulting package for `ClimbingStats` project is perfectly relocatable. I would suggest to follow that example when prepare package files for your project.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I thought `Boost::boost` would cover all libs.
Now I can compile the library itself but the I still have a problem when using the library in a downstream project: the `Config.cmake` file associated to the lib now exports e.g. `Boost::iostreams` as part of the `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` property, which is not properly consumed by the downstream lib (it occurs in linker statement as `-lBoost::iostreams`, which leads to an error, ofc). Is this a problem of the downstream cmake, which should replace the string in the property or is it wrong that the string is in the property?

Comment: It is not CMake who should generate the "main" `XXXConfig.cmake` file with `install(EXPORT)`. This file should be written by you and call `find_dependency` from it. See that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51293903/3440745).

Comment: Yes, my bad again, that was a mixup. Actually, I meant the `XXXConfigTargets.cmake` file associated to the lib now exports e.g. `Boost::iostreams` as part of the `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` property, which is not properly consumed by the downstream lib (it occurs in linker statement as `-lBoost::iostreams`, which leads to an error, ofc). Is this a problem of the downstream cmake, which should replace the string in the property or is it wrong that the string is in the property? 
**Furthermore**, I added `find_dependency` to the `XXXConfig.cmake`, unfortunately to no avail.

Comment: Please, show your `XXXConfig.cmake`. You may add it to the question post.

Comment: Did I do what you meant, by putting in 
```find_dependency(Boost)
find_dependency(Lua)```
in the `cartographer-config.cmake`?

Comment: Yes, but you need to modify `cartographer-config.cmake.in`: as you can see from the comments in the file `cartographer-config.cmake`, that file is *autogenerated* from `cartographer-config.cmake.in`. (And it is better to show the original `cartographer-config.cmake.in`, not the *autogenerated* `cartographer-config.cmake`.)

Comment: Edited the Question again to show the `cartographer-config.cmake.in`. My problem still remains, as described in the comment I posted May 27 at 11:16 (see above).
Can cmake replace the strings like `Boost::iostreams` in the `XXXConfigTargets.cmake` with a proper string that is meaningful for the linker (e.g. here: `boost_iostreams`)?
 The calls to `find_dependency` will not do this (and if I understood correctly that is not their purpose)

Comment: Oh, I got it. Original call to `find_package(Boost)` in the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/cartographer-project/cartographer/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L38)  passes `COMPONENTS` list for the `find_package(Boost)` call. Exactly this option is responsible for creating IMPORTED targets like `Boost::iostream`. When call `find_dependency` you need to pass the same `COMPONENTS` list, which contains `iostream` and, in case of Windows, `zlib`. (And, in case of Windows you need additional line `set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS FALSE)` before `find_dependency`). I have updated the answer for that case.